# Implementing ng2-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to explore trying to use ng2-file-upload but having some trouble understanding how to implement it as the readme is quite sparse. Are there anymore details that can help me get started on this. I am trying to create a demo app to upload images and save them in the server as a start.

I checked out the demo page here, http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

A few questions if anyone can help.

1. For the typescript page, const URL refers to an API and in the example, it is 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/'.
2. There is a file-catcher.js file in the demo/component/file-upload directory. Can anyone explain what this does and whether it is needed? Seems like an express app.

Or any other way to implement an image upload function is also welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try upload without 3rd-Party?

Service:

```
export class WebService {

constructor(private http:Http) {

}

 public makeFileRequest(files:File[]):Observable<any> {
   return Observable.create(observer => {
       let formData:FormData = new FormData(),
           xhr:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

       for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
           formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
       }

       xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
           if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
               if (xhr.status === 200) {
                   observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                   observer.complete();
               } else {
                   observer.error(xhr.response);
               }
           }
       };

       xhr.open('POST', CONSTS.baseURL + "/api/uploadFile", true);
       xhr.send(formData);
   });
}
```

In component:

```
import {Component, NgZone} from "@angular/core";
import {WebService} from "../services/services";
@Component({
 templateUrl:"./your.template.html"
})

 export class YourComponent{
 public fileEvent=null;
 private fileName;
 public validTypes = ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document","application/msword","application/pdf"];
 private errorFileType:boolean = false;
 private fileUploadedSuccessFully:boolean = false;
 private uploading:boolean = false;
 public uploadingMessage = "Gönder";

 constructor(public webService:WebService,public zone:NgZone){

 }
 uploadFile(event){
   if(this.validTypes.indexOf(event.target.files[0].type)!=-1){
       this.fileEvent = event;
       this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
       this.errorFileType = false;
   }
   else {
       this.errorFileType = true;
   }
 }
   upload(){
   this.uploading = true;
   this.uploadingMessage = "Yükleniyor";

   this.webService.makeFileRequest(this.fileEvent.target.files).subscribe((data)=>this.zone.run(()=>{
       this.fileUploadedSuccessFully = true;
       this.uploadingMessage = "Yüklendi!";
   }));
}
```

in html template:

```
 <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
 <span (click)="uploading==false?upload():null" [ngClass]="{'upload-disable': uploading==true}">{{uploadingMessage}}</span>
```

Comment: I hope you still remember this :) I'm using your solution but the angular-cli is refreshing the site each time I upload a file. I have this question open: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619520/where-to-upload-image-in-angular-2-project could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in order

1) Const URL, https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com refers to the BASE_URL where the application runs and /api refers to the path that needs to be called for file uplaoding. So in your app, you have to include your BASE_URL followed by /api to upload the file.

2) File-catcher.js file is the most important file which is actually performing the upload in the express server using multer package. If you are not using express server, then you have to include the multer package in your server to upload the file. 
I could suggest you to read [**this tutorial**](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/upload-files-to-node-js-using-angular-2/) and about [**multer**](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for better understanding and easy usage.

Comment: Thanks Aish123, will go through the links and understand more. :)