# Where to upload image in angular 2 project?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have an app that can upload images. Everything is working fine, I;m not having issues with the upload itself...
But I have issues because as soon as I upload the image and storage in the server, the angular-clie reload the page.

At first, I was uploading the images to /src/assets
Then I relized that angular-clie is refreshing the page, because it detect some new content on the folder it's listeing. So I change that and now the images are being uploading to /resources (outside src folder) so now angular-clie is not refreshing the page... But they are not vissible for the web app as they are not in the "public folder".

So my question... Where should I upload the images without fire a page reload? / Or how I add an exception to angular-cli?

As backend I'm using Java with Spring, and that part is working fine.
My angular2 structure is:

```
/
/resources
/src
/src/app
/src/assets
/dist
```

etc...

My angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
  "name": "ng2angle"

    },
    "apps": [
      {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
          "assets",
          "favicon.ico"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "styles": [
          "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
          "styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "app/core/preloader/preloader.js"
        ],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
          "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
          "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      }
    ],
    "e2e": {
      "protractor": {
        "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
      }
    },
    "lint": [
      {
        "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
      },
      {
        "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
      },
      {
        "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
      }
    ],
    "test": {
      "karma": {
        "config": "./karma.conf.js"
      }
    },
    "defaults": {
      "styleExt": "scss",
      "prefixInterfaces": false,
      "inline": {
        "style": false,
        "template": false
      },
      "spec": {
        "class": false,
        "component": true,
        "directive": true,
        "module": false,
        "pipe": true,
        "service": true
      }
    }
  }
```

COnsole Log when uploading:
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

```
{success: true, code: null, data: {…}}
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
[WDS] App updated. Reloading...
```

Function to sent file to backend:

```
save(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        let headers = new Headers();
        /** No need to include Content-Type in Angular 4 */
        let options = new RequestOptions(this.createAuthHeadersForUpload());
        return this._http.post(`${this.baseUrl + '/save'}`, formData, options)
            .map((response: Response) => <JsonResponse>response.json())
            .do(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
      }
      else
        return null;
  }
```

Comment: If you want the pictures to be inside the `angular` project, there's an `assets` folder, which should already contain a `.svg` file that's generated when the project is created.

Comment: Note that you should not be using the Angular CLI live server in production (that's pretty explicit in the logs).

Comment: I have the assets in /src/assets, not in /src/app (should I create it there?) But when I upload the images there anguular-cli reloads the page automatically.
This is the console log:
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
{success: true, code: null, data: {…}}
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
[WDS] App updated. Reloading...

Comment: @jonrsharpe is in my localmachine during the development

Comment: I added more information

Comment: You can prevent `ng serve` from watching for file system changes with `--poll -1`, but then it won't reload for code changes either. There's no way to specify a folder not to watch, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I did this and it don't work as I expected... the page didn't reload.. so that was the good part... but the file was not reachable... I get 404 when I try to see the new image... I take a look at the url and it was fine... I stopped angular-cli and started it again, and then I was able to see the image... So it is like angular-cli not served the new files if I run it with --poll -1.

I'm just trying to upload and image (something pretty basic) where is the issue? in the angular cli or in my code?

Comment: Paying a bit more attention to this, it seems that angular-cli (in the regular ng serve) give 404 when it tries to get access to the files the first time, so it reloads the page... And then if I tried to access to the image, I'm able to. But I need to show this without refreshing as when the page realods the user lost the information he was inputting

Comment: The issue is in your code. You need to put the image somewhere that can actually serve it, probably *not* just dump it alongside your app. Think S3 bucket, backend, ...

Comment: Edit lint like below:


"lint": [
      {
        "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
"exclude": "**/resources/**/*"  
      },
      {
        "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
      },
      {
        "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
      }
    ],

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm doing that... I have a Java app that stored the image. But It is storaging it in the web app directory so It can be available for the web app... I'm in development phase, so I'm testing locally.

Comment: After thinking about this.... is this the correct solution? Or should I upload the image to a different server where I have access.. like...My web app use a server A, my backend app use a server B, and the images are stored in a resources folder in server B so A has access.

Comment: Finnally, in the real server using apache this issue is not happening... So I will need to test this functionality directly there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I couldn't make it works in my local environment, but I have to have a dev environment, where I can store the images and open them from there... Anyway, this is not happening in PRD as there I have an Apache server.